# when to use Scenario scenario parameter in cucumber jvm

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I searched for exact reason & significance of using **Scenario scenario** parameter ( import cucumber.api.Scenario; ) but didn't clear answer.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks > Scenario Hooks section doesn't explain in detail.

Please give real world examples of the benefits

Comment: not sure why someone has downvoted this question without proper clarification/comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get access to these *methods*:

[image]

Benefits depend on you project needs. Try them out and see where in your project they can help.

Here are some exmples:

Get scenario name in the `@Before` hook, print it or save it for other uses (like reports):

```
@Before
public void before(Scenario scenario) {
    String scenarioName = scenario.getName();
    System.out.println("Scenario: " + scenarioName);
}
```

Get the scenario status in the `@After` hook.

```
@After
public void after(Scenario scenario) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```